# Rendering lists using v-for in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to render a list of names using v-for. I have an array of names and I am able to create the template and render the names in the div. What I want to do is if I add any new object in my data, how can I render that part onwards of the data in a new template. So for example, everything until name 'michael' is rendered in one div, but if I add a new name to the data, from that point onwards the names should be rendered inside another template. 
Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/VwwqPbQ) showing my problem

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      myArray: [{
          name: 'Sam',
          value: 'sam'
        },
        {
          name: 'Gary',
          value: 'gary'
        },
        {
          name: 'Smith',
          value: 'smith'
        },
        {
          name: 'Sunny',
          value: 'sunny'
        },
        {
          name: 'Michael',
          value: 'michael'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire" class="ml-4">
    <template>
      <div v-for="person in myArray" key="person.name">
        {{person.name}}
      </div>
    </template>
    <template>
      //New names should be rendered here from the new values added to the data?
    </template>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. I hope I have explained my need. If not let me know.

Comment: Use two separate arrays?

Comment: I want to keep one unfortunately. I am trying to make it a bit dynamic.

Comment: Why do they need to be in the same array?  You could easily merge the two arrays later if need be.

Comment: Why do you need a single array? If you need to combine them at some point, you can do so with `Array.prototype.concat()`.

Comment: Well i am trying to keep it one array because i would most probably be getting an array from an API call eventually.

Comment: Yep, so have one array for the remote data and another array for your new data. Keep it simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do somethings like this

```html
<template>
  ...
  <v-app id="inspire" class="ml-4">
    <template>
       <!-- Names -->
      <div v-for="person in myArray1" key="person.name">
        {{person.name}}
      </div>
    </template>
    <template>
      <!-- New names -->
      <div v-for="person in myArray2" key="person.name">
        {{person.name}}
      </div>
    </template>
    <v-btn @click="addNewPerson">
      Add
    </v-btn>
  </v-app>
  ...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      myArray: [{
          name: 'Sam',
          value: 'sam'
        },
        {
          name: 'Gary',
          value: 'gary'
        },
        {
          name: 'Smith',
          value: 'smith'
        },
        {
          name: 'Sunny',
          value: 'sunny'
        },
        {
          name: 'Michael',
          value: 'michael'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myArray1() {
      return this.myArray.filter(it => it.recent !== true)
    },
     myArray2() {
      return this.myArray.filter(it => it.recent === true)
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addNewPerson() {
      this.myArray.push({
        name: 'Michael 1',
        value: 'michael 2',
        recent: true // add this
      })
    }
  }
  ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is actually a really great way of doing this, however can you filter using name instead of using the ```true``` property?

Comment: How did you add a new name?

Comment: actually nevermind. i don't really need to filter by name. This will work just fine. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you want, you will either need to use a `computed` value that returns newly added values by checking if they are in a position that exceeds the original link (or any other method really), so if you first load the component and store that the existing array has 5 elements, you can have a computed that returns the first 5 elements and put that into the first `div`, then another computed that returns elements 6+ into the second `div`. Otherwise, you will need to use two separate arrays.

Keep in mind I'm using `this.$data` here in the example, but the data and the values should be in the store, so it'd be `this.$store.state.myArray` instead.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(element, index) of getExisting" :key="index">{{element.name}}</div>
        <div v-for="(element, index) of getNew" :key="index">{{element.name}}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        created () {
            this.existing = this.myArray.length
        },
        myArray: [
            { name: 'John' },
            { name: 'James' }
        ],
        existing: null
    }),
    computed: {
        getExisting () {
            return this.$data.myArray.slice(0, this.existing)
        },
        getNew () {
            return this.$data.myArray.slice(this.existing, myArray.length)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is kind of the approach i was taking but couldn't figure out how to do that so if you could provide an example that would be great. :)

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: I tried using this logic but it doesn't seem to be working: https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/VwwqPbQ?editors=1011. Could you please check what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, the data property is set up incorrectly, so it isn't functioning.
`
data: () => ({

})
`
This is a shorthand form of having a returning object. Data must be a function returning an object. For CodePen, you don't necessarily need it reactive since it's running every edit anyway for what you're doing.